# What's the role of slug in PrestoSQL

Tags: presto, trino

PrestoSQL 3XX introduces one param 'slug' in QueuedStatementResource, so what's the role of slug? What's the difference between 'slug' and 'token'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query `slug` is a one-time security token protecting query results from other users. Before Dain & I added it, users could intercept ("steal") other users' query results.

`token` is just an incremental number so that next batch of results has a new URI. (Using same URI for subsequent batches wouldn't be RESTful.)

You can learn more at the [Presto Community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).
(this seems beyond SO's scope)